# Interpolation of 2d data(velocity(x,y)) over 1D array (time)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a list of velocities over time. Is there a way to interpolate that data over size of that list (time)?
To make it more clear here is a simple code:

```
import numpy as np
v_list = []
v_time1 = [[1,1], [2,2]] #2D
v_time2 = [[0,1], [3,4]] #2D
v_list.append(v_time1,v_time2)
time = np.size(v_list) #1D
```

My goal is to interpolate data contained in v_list over time, so I can "call" it depending on desired time. Something like this:

```
v_desired_time = interpolated_velocities(desired_time) #2D
```

Cheers!

Comment: It is not clear what your code is trying to do.  What are the values in `v_time1` and `v_time2`?  Are they x, and y velocity values or are they time values?   What are the values of `v1` and `v2` that are appended to `v_list`?

Comment: Typed it wrong. Check it now. Why does it matter what are the values in those matrices? They are just some random numbers I've put here to make it clear what I want to do. If I can interpolate this presented data with shape of [2,2] then I can interpolate my data which is [840, 620]. It's completely irrelevant what those numbers above represent.

Comment: I wanted to know if they were time values or velocity values (actual number does not matter), so I could try to determine what to do with them.

Comment: Let's put it like this: a radar is recording velocities in x-direction at 4 points. That's what those numbers up there represent. It is saving data every hour, for two hours. That's why there are two matrices up there. I made it as simple as it can be, one matrix for every measurement. And now let' say i want to know the velocities at t = 0.5 hrs. It's not about physics or velocities. It's about interpolating data.

Comment: Is there a reason the four measurements are stored in a 2x2 array, and not, say, a 1-D array with length 4?

Comment: Yes. Each position in the matrix represents the coordinates of a measuring point. You think it could be done with converting it into 1D array, using numpy.ravel for example?

Comment: No, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).  It can handle the values of the function being arrays.

For example,

```
In [35]: from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

Here are your measurements.  I'll put them into a numpy array called `v`:

```
In [36]: v_time1 = [[1,1], [2,2]] #2D

In [37]: v_time2 = [[0,1], [3,4]] #2D

In [38]: v = np.array([v_time1, v_time2])

In [39]: v
Out[39]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [3, 4]]])
```

`t` holds the time values:

```
In [40]: t = np.arange(v.shape[0])

In [41]: t
Out[41]: array([0, 1])
```

Create the interpolator.  By default, it uses linear interpolation:

```
In [42]: f = interp1d(t, v, axis=0)
```

Check the values of the interpolator at several values of time:

```
In [43]: f(0)
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])

In [44]: f(0.5)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0.5,  1. ],
       [ 2.5,  3. ]])

In [45]: f(1)
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Magic. I was doing it before without specifying the axis of interpolation. That was the problem. Thank you.